# Show that : $x^4 - 2x^2y^2 + y^2 \geq 0$ for $x\in D$ where D is a domain around $O(0,0)$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm having a bit of trouble showing the following problem :

> Show that : $x^4 - 2x^2y^2 + y^2 \geq 0$ for $x\in D$ where D is a domain around $O(0,0)$.

I guess that for $|x| \leq1/2$ it holds : $$x^4-2x^2y^2 + y^2 \geq \frac{1}{2}y^2$$

which means that $x^4-2x^2y^2 + y^2 \geq 0$ for $|x| < 1/2$, but I can't see how I could prove that.

Excuse me if it's elementary, sometimes I'm a bit blind on inequality proofs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
\begin{align*}
x^4-2x^2y^2+y^2&=x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4+y^2-y^4\\
&=\left(x^2-y^2\right)
^2+y^2-y^4\end{align*}

it follows that $x^4-2x^2y^2+y^2\ge0\;\Longleftarrow\;y^2-y^4\ge 0\;\iff\;|y|\le1$.

Comment: The first equivalence $\iff$ in the last line is actually only a reverse implication $\impliedby$.

Answer (score 2):

We are in a domain around $(0,0)$, in particular $y <1$ and $(1-y^2)>0$, so
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^4-2x^2y^2+y^2 = (x^2-y^2)^2 +y^2(1-y^2) > 0 .
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

It's $$(x^2-y^2)^2+y^2-y^4\geq0,$$ which is true for $-1\leq y\leq1$.